# How do I test to see a method is Abstract in java Junit 5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit5

I have an abstract class called Animal ànd inside it I have an abstract method called multiply. How do I check if this method is abstract or not using JUnit 5?

```
public abstract class Animal {
    private final int age;
    private final int speed;
    
    public Animal (int age,int speed) {
        if(age > 0) {
            this.age = age;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age can't be less than 0");
        }
        if(speed > 0) {
            this.speed = speed;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Speed can't be less than 0");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    @Override 
    public boolean equals(Object anotherObject) {
           if (this == anotherObject) {  
                  return true;  
              }else {
                  return false;
              }
    }
    public abstract Animal[] multiply(int n);
    
    private boolean isFaster(Animal a) {
        if(this.getSpeed() >a.getSpeed()) {
            return true;
        }else {
        return false;
        }
    }
    
    private boolean isOlder(Animal a) {
        if(this.getAge() >a.getAge()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass()+ "is " + this.getAge() + " years old, is " +this.getSpeed() +" units fast.";
        
    }
    public final int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public final int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }



}
```

I know how to get if the class is abstract by entering this

```
Class<Animal> clazz = Animal.class;
        Assertions.assertTrue(Modifier.isAbstract(clazz.getModifiers()));
```

how do I do the equivalent for an abstract method?

Comment: What is `Modifier`? Take a look at reflection in general. This isn't anything specific to JUnit. Also, why would you need to do this?

Comment: You should generally not be testing this sort of implementation detail at all.

Comment: Yes, one important thing about testing is learning _what_ to test.